# How to enable port 8080 for apache to serve APIs

Tags: apache2

I'm using ec2 instance to server my Go apis. When I'm building my APIs then it will simply access by `http://Ip:8080/api`. After that I'm working on frontend part to integrate my APIs I used react for it. In local everything is fine and running. But when I deploy my frontend on the server then it will show me error of fetching result from APIs `http://Ip:8080/api` need to use `https://ip:8080/api` then I created a sub domain and apply SSL on it and I successfully bind my IP with that subdomain and I'm able to access images which are on server folder path `/var/www/html/images/a.png` for that I'm using Apache server. But now when I run my Go services and run it with the subdomain name like `https://subdomain:8080/api` then it will not accessible. I'm pasting my `ports.conf`

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
Listen 80
Listen 8080
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
        Listen 8080
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Please let me know if any this is needed and also if I'm skipping something.

Comment: Can add log and see if the port number is set.
AFAIK, while deploying in ec2, public instance and setting a domain or sub-domain, we usually don't set any port, it takes the http default port which is 80, while requesting we need not explicitly mention the default port, since it is default.

Comment: But I want to run my apis with `https` not with the `http` @LunaLovegood